# Norm and Sqrt[Total[Abs[]^2]]

Tags: numerics

Here, I want to obtain a norm `` Norm[{7.834622802200601`*^-12, 6.34846061071273`*^-8,  0.00006961932410684564`, 0.010332423825283125`, 0.2075322802487482`, 0.5641312262188423`, 0.2075322802487482`, 0.010332423825283125`,  0.00006961932410684564`, 6.34846061071273`*^-8,  7.834622802200601`*^-12}] ``, which gives `0.636079`.

But another way `` Sqrt[Total@ Abs[{7.834622802200601`*^-12, 6.34846061071273`*^-8,  0.00006961932410684564`, 0.010332423825283125`,  0.2075322802487482`, 0.5641312262188423`, 0.2075322802487482`,  0.010332423825283125`, 0.00006961932410684564`,  6.34846061071273`*^-8, 7.834622802200601`*^-12}]^2] `` gives `1.`.

So why these two ways are so different?

Comment: Compare  `Total@Abs[{a,b}]^2`  and  `Total[Abs[{a,b}]^2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two methods are not equivalent.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

vec = Array[a, 4];

Norm[vec]

(* Sqrt[Abs[a[1]]^2 + Abs[a[2]]^2 + Abs[a[3]]^2 + Abs[a[4]]^2] *)

Sqrt[Total@Abs[vec]^2]

(* Sqrt[(Abs[a[1]] + Abs[a[2]] + Abs[a[3]] + Abs[a[4]])^2] *)
```

The results are not equivalent. You must control the order in which the operations are performed:

```
Norm[vec] == Sqrt[Total@(Abs[vec]^2)] == Sqrt[Total[Abs[vec]^2]]

(* True *)
```